# Why can I not save changes to my database C# LINQ

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sqlite, linq

I am a student trying to create a sqlite database with C#. When I try to save my commits to the database I get this error:
Inner Exception
SqliteException: SQLite Error 1: 'table Customers has no column named FirstName'.

This is the line that is generating the error:
db.SaveChanges();

I know for fact that Customers does have a column named FirstName.

[From Model.cs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42XuS.png)

[From Migrations Folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oRkau.png)

Edit: Just realized I forgot to run (dotnet ef database update) as Kilarn123 suggested. Now I hav another error in the console when I run that command:
SQLite Error 1: 'table "Customers" already exists'.

Do I need to delete the table or the database and run it all again? I'm not sure how it can already exist.

Comment: Has the migration been applied to the database (with Database.Migrate() from the context or with Update-Database from package manger console) ? otherwise you can check the .db file directly with a tool like sqlite browser or similar

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by Database.Migrate(). In the console I used this command to initialize the database:  dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate. Where would I find the .db file?

Comment: if you use the dotnet cli, you can run `dotnet ef database update` to apply the migration to your database. For the .db file, i don't really know your settings or anything so i can't tell where it is

Comment: I just realized I forgot to run (dotnet ef database update) after (dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate). I went back to do so and got new errors: SQLite Error 1: 'table "Customers" already exists'. Do I need to delete the databse and try to rebuild it? Not sure how to do so.

Comment: [Please do not post images of code or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: I would recommend the guide [Getting Started with EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/overview/first-app?tabs=netcore-cli) for a step-by-step instruction on how to create a simple database.

Comment: Is it possible to share how is your model and Dbcontext class constructed? Are you using Migration command or using database first approach?

Comment: If you have previously run the migration successfully and only added the FirstName column to the Customers table, then you do not need to run the migration again. Instead, you can modify the Customers table directly by adding the FirstName column manually using a SQLite client or by running a SQL script. You can also use a tool like DB Browser for SQLite to view and modify the contents of your SQLite database.
If you have not previously run the migration successfully, you can delete the existing Customers table and then run the migration again.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. wenbingeng-MST was correct. I had previously run the migration successfully and without the FirstName column to the Customers table in a previous project attempt. I found the location of the database, deleted it, and reran my migrations. Thanks everyone for the help.

Comment: Hi, I posted my comment as an answer. If it is helpful to you, you can mark it so that it can help more people.